# htmlagilitypack xpath incorrect

Tags: c#, xpath, html-agility-pack

I have a problem that my xpath is not working.

I am trying to get the url from Google.com's search result list into a string list.

But i am unable to reach on url using Xpath.

Please help me in correcting my xpath. Also tell me what should be on the place of ??

```
HtmlWeb hw = new HtmlWeb();
List<string> urls = new List<string>();
HtmlAgilityPack.HtmlDocument doc = hw.Load("http://www.google.com/search?q=" +txtURL.Text.Replace(" " , "+"));
HtmlNodeCollection linkNodes = doc.DocumentNode.SelectNodes("//div[@class='f kv']");
foreach (HtmlNode linkNode in linkNodes)
{
    HtmlAttribute link = linkNode.Attributes["?????????"];
    urls.Add(link.Value);

}
for (int i = 0; i <= urls.Count - 1; i++)
{
    if (urls.ElementAt(i) != null)
    {
        if (IsValid(urls.ElementAt(i)) != true)
        {
            grid.Rows.Add(urls.ElementAt(i));

        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Why do you expect the URL to be in an attribute of a `div`?

Comment: i know this is incorrect. I want help on this

Comment: I also pick xpath from Chrome but that is not working tooo.

Comment: From the page source, I would say you need to select the `cite` elements and get their `InnerText`.

Comment: I did tried that too, But i think i am mistaken on xpath. Can you please help me in correcting xpath?

Comment: we can see there are always 10 results shown in google search page. I just want to loop through all those search results.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The correct XPath is `"//div[@class='kv']/cite"`. The `f` class you see in the browser element inspector is (probably) added after the page is rendered using javascript.

Also, the link text is not in an attribute, you can get it using the `InnerText` property of the `<div>` element(s) obtained at the earlier step.

I changed these lines and it works:

```
var linkNodes = doc.DocumentNode.SelectNodes("//div[@class='kv']/cite");

foreach (HtmlNode linkNode in linkNodes)
{
    urls.Add(linkNode.InnerText);
}
```

*There's a caveat though: some links are trimmed (you'll see a `...` in the middle)*

Comment: Everything is working fine, Thanks a lot for the help. But one thing i didn't get that why every link is followed by - cached - similar

Comment: @user1647974 Sorry, didn't notice that the first time. The solution is to select the inner `<cite>` elements, like Oded proposed in his answer. I've updated my answer too

Comment: Thanks a lot for helping me on this, Now my application is giving desired result. Thanks a lot buddy..........

Comment: Can You also assist me in finding 100 results from google in one go?

Comment: And can we fire a click event through htmlagilitypack? If yes please tell me how to do it?

Answer (score 1):

The URLs seem to live in the `cite` element under that selected `div`s, so the XPath to select those is `//div[@class='f kv']/cite`.

Now, since these contain markup but you only want the text, select the `InnerText` of the selected nodes. Note that these do not begin with `http://`.

```
HtmlNodeCollection linkNodes = 
                       doc.DocumentNode.SelectNodes("//div[@class='f kv']/cite");
foreach (HtmlNode linkNode in linkNodes)
{
    HtmlAttribute link = linkNode.InnerText;
    urls.Add(link.Value);
}
```

Comment: The xpath still not working, thorwing error for null in linknodes.

Comment: @user1647974 - It works for me with a test page I saved (view source) from google

Comment: Can you tell me how to fire a click event using htmlagilitypack, or by any other api?

Comment: @user1647974 - You can't though the HAP. It just parses HTML. Not sure what you are looking to do, but if you want to click, look for a web automation tool like selenium or watin.

Comment: I know selenium and watin, But these tools are browser based, I don't want to use browser in my application